# "People over 60(age)", How can I rephrase this expression?

Tags: grammar

> It is predicted that there will be more people over 60 than under 15 in 20 years.

I found a sentence above while reading an English practice book made by Koreans(not experts in English). I have two questions.

1) Is this sentence sound right to native speakers of English?

2) Is there any way to repharse "people over 60" or the whole sentence?

For the second question, I thought that I might rephrase it into something like "people older than 60" but was not sure because this could make the sentence too bulksome and confusing. Like,

> It is predicted that there will be more people older than 60 than under 15 in 20 years.

Comment: *"... people over the age of 60 ..."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think "over 60 and under 15" is a common and more  "politically correct" way to express the idea referring to age. I'd avoid using the term "older" which is too explicit about age.

As you can see from [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=people%20over%2060%2Cpeople%20older%20than%2060%2Cpeople%20over%20sixty%2Cpeople%20older%20than%20sixty&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpeople%20over%2060%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpeople%20older%20than%2060%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpeople%20over%20sixty%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpeople%20older%20than%20sixty%3B%2Cc0) "over 60" is a much more common expression.

Usage examples:

[10 Effective Yoga Poses For Women Over 60](http://www.stylecraze.com/articles/effective-yoga-poses-for-women-over-60/#gref)

[Fashion for women over 60](http://sixtyandme.com/tag/fashion-for-women-over-60/)

Answer (score 0):

In terms of word order alone, it is *over age 60* and not *over 60 age* although there is often no need to use the word *age* when the context makes that clear.